# Convert Certificate in DER or PEM to pkcs12

Tags: openssl

I have a certificate in DER format it is complete has public key, private key and intermediate certificates location. I need to use it to sign a Java document. I can not use JKS for a third-party library account, I need the certificate to be in pkcs12 format. I got lots of information here and on other sites, but so far I have not found a solution. the most common commands are convert to pem

`openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.der -out certificate.pem`

and many speak of

`openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.p12 -inkey *** -in *** -inform der -certfile ***`
to convert, but this command needs files that I could not get.

In short I have a file that contains all necessary information to convert to pkcs12. It works its import in access to OSX keys and export to pkcs12, however I wish to perform command line (openssl).

Any light?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by a "file" that contains all the necessary information is a PEM formatted file with the private key, certificate and then one or more intermediate certificates.

e.g.

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
>
> xxx
>
> -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>
> xxx
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>
> xxx
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----

If that's the case then converting it is easy.  All you really need is to point to the pem file with the command you already pointed to.

e.g.

> openssl pkcs12 -export -out test.pfx -in test.pem

You only need to supply the other arguments (like -inkey and -certfile) when the files are in separate files and/or formats.

Answer (score 0):

Following command should work in your case:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pkcs12 -in cert.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Those of you getting key errors when trying the pkcs12 export from PEMs, you need to manually specify the key file you used with the CSR even though the internet says the PEM file should include it.

I got the PEM file from Digicert and my software just says it can't import it even though I entered the key passphrase. I then used OpenSSL and the -inkey flag to use the key that was generated with my CSR, then was able to export the P12 file that my software wanted.